# Is there any way to go to the end in Minecraft PE without first going to the nether?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is there any way to go to the end in Minecraft pe without first going to the nether or trading? Please be simple and straight to the point.

Comment: What makes you think that you need to go to the nether at all?

Comment: Because you need blaze powder to get eyes of ender.

Comment: In that case, it looks like you have to in order to obtain that powder.  Unless you spawn some.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes you can, but...

Although this is horrifically rare. Each end portal frame block has a specific chance to be generated with an eye of ender already in place. So, in theory, there is a chance to have an end portal that is completely kitted out with all blocks active. Since the amount of fortresses is limited, there is an incredibly low chance for your world to have one of those.

In regards to the other answers:

Sadly, the cleric villagers only sell ender pearl and not eye of ender, therefore you will still need blaze powder, which as far as I was able to find, cannot be found in loot chests of any kind, nor through any amount of crafting except from blaze rods, which themself can only be obtained from blazes in the nether.

So, in a practical sense, there is no way to pass on the nether if you want to reach the end game :)

Comment: The odds, for anyone who cares to know, are exactly 1 in 1 trillion. That's four times rarer than walking outside and getting struck by lightning twice in a row.

Comment: Per https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Seed_(level_generation)#Bedrock_Edition, there are only two billion possible worlds that Bedrock Edition can generate, so it is in fact highly likely that no seed that contains a fully-generated end portal exists, and this goes back to being impossible.

Comment: The chance of such a seed existing is about [0.5 percent](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%281+trillion+minus+1%29%2F%281+trillion%29%29%5E%282%5E32%29)

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms 1 in 1 trillion per portal, but there are up to 128 portals per world.

Comment: Additionally, a recent bug, at least in Java Edition, allows for much more frequent partially-filled end portals to generate "partially open" - if the portal lies on a division between chunks and all slots in one of the chunks are full and it's generated first (player approaching from that direction) that part of the portal will generate active. If the portal lies on crossing of four chunks, with a 1-block corner in one chunk, this means only the two adjacent portal frame blocks need to be filled.

Comment: Chance the portal spawns in that location: 4 in 256 so 1/64; chance both slots are filled: 1 in 100, but with 128 portals per world, 1 in 50 worlds will have this corner piece active - providing the player arrived from opportune direction.

Answer (score 1):

**No.** To make **Eyes of Ender** which is necessary for activating the portal, you must craft them from **Ender Pearls and Blaze Powder.** You get **Blaze Powder** by crafting it with **Blaze Rods,** which you get from **Blazes in the Nether**. Unless you can spawn in Blazes in the Overworld using console commands, or hack in some items, or ask another player to give you some from their travels... no.

EDIT: See MatBat's answer, it's more accurate.

Comment: False, @AmitaiNachmany. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

OLD ANSWER

**You actually can.**

Though it may be rare, Villager priest sell Eyes of Ender for a few emeralds. Therefore, if you have a lot of emeralds on hand, you can get to the End without entering the Nether.

One good thing to do to get these emeralds is to trade with Farmers for emeralds. They usually trade emeralds for common materials.

NEW ANSWER

As of this edit, you can no longer buy Eyes of Ender directly. Instead, you have to buy Ender Pearls, then craft the Eyes.

Comment: Wow. I did not know that! The more ya know.

Comment: Yeah, this is actually how I obtained most of my eyes when I played through to the End!

Comment: He added, "or trading." Otherwise, very interesting answer!

Comment: Unless PE has completely different tables the clerics only sale Ender pearls which do not suffice

Comment: ***This answer is now incorrect (I don't know if it was at the time but it is not now). I have looked through the trade tables in the vanilla behavior pack, and while clerics do sell ender pearls, they do not sell eyes of ender.***

Comment: @Penguin thanks for informing me of this! It was true at the time, at the time of posting.

Comment: Yep! Just wanted to sort out possible confusion :)